# Algorithm: T(N) =2^N

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Suppose the number of operations required by a particular algorithm is exactly T(n) = 2^n and our
1.6 Ghz computer performs exactly 1.6 billion operations per second. What is the largest
problem, in terms of n, that can be solved in under a second? In under a day?

I tired 2^1.6 for a second and 2^(1.6*60*24), but I think I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: If you know the number of operations `K`, then the total time to perform them is `t = K / (1.6 B / second)`

Comment: Your title says 2^N, your question says 2N, I think you mean 2^n, should I assume 2^n?

Comment: Yes, sry for the confusion.

Comment: If I don't know k should I just suppose it as t = k / 1.6 ? And I am confused that if the total time is t, and I don't know the k, how should I know the time of it and how do I know what is it for a second or an hour?

Comment: So t(n) is the total time right?

Comment: The first question means: find *n* such that *2^n = 1600000000*

Comment: 24 hours per day * 60 minutes per hour * 60 seconds per minute gives you the number of seconds in a day. Multiply by 1.6 billion to get the number of operations the computer can perform in one day.

Comment: So, ' in a second' is 2^n = 1.6 billion and I need to find n? And ' for a day' is 24*60*60*1.6 operations? Then there is nothing to do with n, which means the answer for 'in a second ' will be 1.6 billion directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we know:

- For being under 1 sec you need to perform less than 1.6*10^9 operations
- The number of operations needed is T(n)=2^n with n the size of the problem

We are looking for the maximum n (the maximum size of the problem under 1 sec). So we can write:

```
2^n <= 1.6*10^9 
n <= ln(1.6*10^9) / ln(2)
n <= 30
```

> So in one sec you can compute a problem of size 30

Now 1 day is 24 * 60 * 60 seconds so:

```
2^n <= 86400 * 1.6*10^9 
n <= ln(86400 * 1.6*10^9)/ln(2)
n <= 46
```

> So in one day you can compute a problem of size 46

Imagine the time needed for a problem of size 64...

Comment: Oh! Thank you! So 1.6 billion is the c(f(n)),but how to know that the full size of the problem is 64?

Comment: The full size of the problem is not 64. It's just an example. With 2^n the time grow very quickly with the size n.

Comment: And I think you forgot to divide ln(2) for the day.